# "locking" files on sdcard -?

Tags: android

Would it be possible for Android service to manipulate some files permissions so that no other application (even on the rooted phone  by root) can access those files on sdcard? For example, if I want to "lock" some documents on sdcard during certain hours?
Thanks,

Comment: `root` can pretty much do anything, whatever the permissions are, as long as the hardware itself doesn't prevent access.

Answer (score 3):

> Would it be possible for Android service to manipulate some files permissions so that no other application (even on the rooted phone by root) can access those files on sdcard?

No, sorry. External storage is open to all, particularly when external storage is on a FAT16-formatted SD card.